# How do I prevent my equation from giving me concatenated numbers?

Tags: javascript, codepen

In this project, Ive written a script which outputs the total cost of any word you type into a textbox. The cost is $6.00 per letter.

I am also to trying to get the script to output the total cost + 7% tax. The issue is that the equation is not calculating the total properly. Instead the equation is putting the cost and tax right next to eachother instead of adding them up. So for example, if the tax is $2.1 and the total is $30, it's wrtiting it like this "$302.1" instead of like this "$32.1".

Here's a snippet of the code (the very last code in the Javascript is the one im having the issue with)

```js
var customTitle;
var cost = 6;

function calculateCost() {
  customTitle = document.getElementById("titleBox").value;
  var titleLetters = customTitle.length;
  var spaceCount = (customTitle.split(" ").length - 1);

  document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = customTitle;
  document.getElementById("checkout").innerHTML = "Your Order Summary";
  document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = "Title: " + customTitle;
  document.getElementById("output3").innerHTML = "Cost: $" + (titleLetters - spaceCount) * cost;
  document.getElementById("output4").innerHTML = "Tax: $" + (titleLetters - spaceCount) * cost * .07;
  document.getElementById("output5").innerHTML = "Total: $" + (titleLetters - spaceCount) * cost * .07 + (titleLetters - spaceCount) * cost;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <main>
    <p>Type your custom title below</p>
    <form>
      <input id="titleBox" type="text">
      <button onclick="calculateCost()" type="button">Generate & Checkout</button>
    </form>
  </main>
  <aside>
    <p id="output1"></p>
    <h3 id="checkout"></h3>
    <p id="output2"></p>
    <p id="output3"></p>
    <p id="output4"></p>
    <p id="output5"></p>
  </aside>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: parseInt, parseFloat, unary + ... there's 3 ways

Comment: Hi Paola. Thank you for trying to be comprehensive by adding images of your complete code, but you should know, the best questions on stack overflow start with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You did a reasonable job of that in your snippet, though I'm sure, if you thought about it, you could pare it down even more to just to bare essentials of what's needed to demonstrate your problem. The community is best helped and can best help you when the minimal amount of code is provided.

Comment: Please upvote the answers you find useful, and happy coding!

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I will take that into consideration next time! Also, I’ve tried to upvote some responses but Im not allowed to just yet since I’m new to the community

Answer (score 1):

You just need to wrap your math in another parentheses.  It is taking the string of `"Total: $" +` as you wanting to concatenate and will convert the output to a string pre-emptively.  If you put the parentheses you get the right math and output.

```js
var customTitle;
var cost = 6;

function calculateCost() {
  customTitle = document.getElementById("titleBox").value;
  var titleLetters = customTitle.length;
  var spaceCount = (customTitle.split(" ").length - 1);

  document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = customTitle;
  document.getElementById("checkout").innerHTML = "Your Order Summary";
  document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = "Title: " + customTitle;
  document.getElementById("output3").innerHTML = "Cost: $" + (titleLetters - spaceCount) * cost;
  document.getElementById("output4").innerHTML = "Tax: $" + (titleLetters - spaceCount) * cost * .07;
  document.getElementById("output5").innerHTML = "Total: $" + ((titleLetters - spaceCount) * cost * .07 + (titleLetters - spaceCount) * cost);
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <main>
    <p>Type your custom title below</p>
    <form>
      <input id="titleBox" type="text">
      <button onclick="calculateCost()" type="button">Generate & Checkout</button>
    </form>
  </main>
  <aside>
    <p id="output1"></p>
    <h3 id="checkout"></h3>
    <p id="output2"></p>
    <p id="output3"></p>
    <p id="output4"></p>
    <p id="output5"></p>
  </aside>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That's great, @Paola, glad it works.  Don't forget to mark the correct answer so future visitors know which answer to look at first to solve the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to easily insert variables, the results of function calls, or evaluate math expressions, is by using [Template literals (Template strings)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```
`string text ${expression} string text`
```

Whatever is in between `${` and `}` gets evaluated before its converted to a string.

```js
var customTitle;
var cost = 6;

function calculateCost() {
  customTitle = document.getElementById("titleBox").value;
  var titleLetters = customTitle.length;
  var spaceCount = (customTitle.split(" ").length - 1);

  document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = customTitle;
  document.getElementById("checkout").innerHTML = "Your Order Summary";
  document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = `Title: ${customTitle}`;
  document.getElementById("output3").innerHTML = `Cost: $${(titleLetters - spaceCount) * cost}`;
  document.getElementById("output4").innerHTML = `Tax: $${(titleLetters - spaceCount) * cost * .07}`;
  document.getElementById("output5").innerHTML = `Total: $${(titleLetters - spaceCount) * cost * .07 + (titleLetters - spaceCount) * cost}`;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <main>
    <p>Type your custom title below</p>
    <form>
      <input id="titleBox" type="text">
      <button onclick="calculateCost()" type="button">Generate & Checkout</button>
    </form>
  </main>
  <aside>
    <p id="output1"></p>
    <h3 id="checkout"></h3>
    <p id="output2"></p>
    <p id="output3"></p>
    <p id="output4"></p>
    <p id="output5"></p>
  </aside>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you!! I’m very knew to JavaScript. I just started learnng it last week for the very first time. So this is something that I will remember and I’m sure will use in the future

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to tackle this issue 1) use parseInt just like I did in the below code or you could also append a unary operator(+) to the problem you faced because; Adding strings that contain numbers does NOT add them. Instead, the strings are concatenated

```js
var customTitle;
var cost = 6;
function calculateCost() {
  customTitle = document.getElementById("titleBox").value;
  var titleLetters = customTitle.length;
  var spaceCount = (customTitle.split(" ").length - 1);
  var totalCost = (titleLetters - spaceCount) * cost * .07 + (titleLetters - spaceCount) * cost
  document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = customTitle;
  document.getElementById("checkout").innerHTML = "Your Order Summary";
  document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = "Title: " + customTitle;
  document.getElementById("output3").innerHTML = "Cost: $" + (titleLetters - spaceCount) * cost;
  document.getElementById("output4").innerHTML = "Tax: $" + (titleLetters - spaceCount) * cost * .07;
  document.getElementById("output5").innerHTML = "Total: $" + totalCost;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <main>
    <p>Type your custom title below</p>
    <form>
      <input id="titleBox" type="text">
      <button onclick="calculateCost()" type="button">Generate & Checkout</button>
    </form>
  </main>
  <aside>
    <p id="output1"></p>
    <h3 id="checkout"></h3>
    <p id="output2"></p>
    <p id="output3"></p>
    <p id="output4"></p>
    <p id="output5"></p>
  </aside>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct, but I want to make sure that OP understands what's going on here. Javascript features [type coercion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Type_coercion), which means that different variable types can be implicitly converted to a different type depending on the context. For example, consider the following (output from the [Node](https://nodejs.org/en/) [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop)):

```js
> 1 + 1
2
> "1" + "1"
'11'
> "1" + 1
'11'
> 2 * 2
4
> "2" + 2 * 2
'24'
> ("2" + 2) * 2
44
```

I'll address each of the six examples in turn:

1. 1 and 1 are both integers. Therefore, + is interpreted to mean integer addition.
2. "1" and "1" are both strings, so + is interpreted to mean string concatenation.
3. "1" is a string, but 1 is an integer. + is not defined for string + integer, but integers can be *coerced* into strings. Thus, 1 => "1", which makes the expression "1" + "1", the same as example (2).
4. 2 and 2 are integers, so * is interpreted as multiplication.
5. "2" is a string and both 2s are integers. However, * has higher [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) than +, so * between 2 and 2 is evaluated first. 2 * 2 = 4, so the expression becomes "2" + 4. Then, as in example (3), 4 is *coerced* to "4", and "2" + "4" is evaluated, resulting in "24".
6. "2" is a string, and 2 is an integer. Since ("2" + 2) is parenthesized, it is evaluated first, and coercion occurs in the same fashion as in example (3). Then, we are left with "22" * 2. * is not defined for string * integer, nor is it defined for string * string. However, it is defined for integer * integer, and "22" can be coerced to 22, an integer, so the expression becomes 22 * 2, which is of course 44.

The other answers have, in various ways, advised you how to avoid + meaning string concatenation when you really mean integer (or other number type) addition, e.g. by parenthesizing the arithmetic portion. I'll leave you to read those answers for concrete examples.

Comment: Thank you for explaining how that works.  I’m new to the community so I am not able to upvote yet.